# vue and google map infowindow

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using vue and google map, and I want a real time experience by updating the data displayed in the info window. I have tried following:

```
var infoStr =   
'<table class="">'+                                    
   '<tbody>' +
       '<tr>' +
          '<td colspan="2">{{testInfo}}</td>' +
       '</tr>' +                                        
    '</tbody>'+
'</table >';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: infoStr
});

global.infoWindow = infowindow;
infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

The application displays {{testInfo}} like it was a string and is not bound. Is there anyway to bind data in the InfoWindow so I can bind it to Vue data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you put `{{testInfo}}` into the variable `infoStr` you are making it static, therefore it will only have value of `{{testinfo}}` at the time the infowindow is created.

As a workaround I suggest that you add `id="info-win-1"` attribute to your infowindow code.

```
var infoStr =   
   '<table class="">'+                                    
     '<tbody>' +
     '<tr>' +
       '<td id="info-win-1" colspan="2">{{testInfo}}</td>' +
     '</tr>' +                                        
     '</tbody>'+
   '</table >';
```

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: infoStr
});

That way you can dynamically change the content using `document.getElementById("info-win-1").innerHTML = testInfo` from your vue app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When will the element be in the DOM? I tried following:  infowindow.open(map, marker);
                document.getElementById("info-win").innerHTML = 'ikke sat'; but at this point the element is not available (i get an null reference og getElement)?

Comment: Check this out Render [Fucntions & JSX](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)